# select top 2 rows every 5 rows in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I want to select top two rows every 5 rows in pandas dataframe. How could I do this?

Consider the following dataframe:

```
col1  | col2 | col3 
1     | 1    | 1
2.    | 2.   | 2
3.    | 3.   | 3 
4     | 4    | 4 
5.    | 5.   | 5 
6.    | 6.   | 6
7.    | 7.   | 7
```

I would like to get the following values

```
    col1  | col2 | col3 
    1     | 1    | 1
    2.    | 2.   | 2
```

and

```
    col1  | col2 | col3
    6.    | 6.   | 6
    7.    | 7.   | 7
```

I will really appreciate the help!!!

Comment: `df.groupby(df.index//5).head(2)`?

Comment: awesome, that is it. if you want to post it as an answer @HenryYik I can accept it and you could that credit

Comment: @HenryYik that approach was quite good!! NICE !!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use floor division on the index and `groupby` on it with `head`:

```
df.groupby(df.index//5).head(2)
```